# Making a list of lists with variable size

Tags: python, list

I'm writing a program that will accept up to five numbers and find if they're prime or not. If a number is not prime it will find their prime factors. Then it will calculate the LCM of the initial numbers. The code I've written so far is this:

```
def prime(n):
    if n > 1:
        for i in range (2,n):
            if n % i == 0:
                return False
    return True
def length(n):
    if len(n) > 5:
        return True
    return False
toggle = False
enter_numbers = True
zero_one_neg = True
square = False
prime_list = [ [] for i in range(100) ]
lcm_list = [ [] for i in range(100)]
while enter_numbers:
    nums = list(map(int, input('\nEnter up to five natural numbers greater than 1 separated by commas. Enter at least two if you want to calculate their LCM: ').split(',')))
    for i in range (len(nums)):
        if nums[i] <= 1:
            zero_one_neg = True
            print('\nNo zeroes, ones or negatives. Start over. ')
            if length(nums) and zero_one_neg:
                print('\nNo more than five numberes. Start over. ')
                break
            break
        else:
            zero_one_neg = False
    if length(nums) and not zero_one_neg:
        print('\nNo more than five numbers. Start over. ')
    elif not length(nums) and not zero_one_neg:
        enter_numbers = False
for i in range (len(nums)):
    for j in range (2,nums[i]):
        if nums[i] % j == 0:
            lcm_list[i].append(j)
            if prime(j):
                prime_list[i].append(j)
            toggle = True
    if not toggle:
        print('\n', nums[i] ,'is a prime number.')
    if toggle:
        print('\n', nums[i] ,'is not a prime number. It\'s prime factors are: ',prime_list[i])
        print(lcm_list[i])
        toggle = False
print(len(prime_list))
```

It's not complete of course. It runs ok but I don't like the fact i have to preset the sizes of `prime_list` and `lcm_list`. How can I dynamically set their sizes?

Comment: Hi, for the best chance of a solid answer, https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example please reference this link when you are asking a question.

Comment: why constraint the `lcm_list` and `prime_list` in the first place, remove the list iteration within them initially then append per normal so when you have a prime number than append it's LCMs to the list that it way it will be dynamic.

Comment: or you can use a dictionary instead of list.

Comment: @FishingCode could you please provide the code equivalent of what you are saying?

Comment: so both those lists you created are now nested lists? what are you trying to achieve is the first question? if you want to **dynamically set their sizes** then you have to remove the hard-coded iteration within the two lists :-)

Comment: @FishingCode yes I want them to be nested lists. That is because if I input say 4,6 both are divisible by 2. Therefore the final list will contain two 2s. I want them to be separate. I don't know if I make sense i'm really a beginner to Python and programming in general>

Comment: ok I see, that sounds good in that case once you do retrieve the LCMs you could just append like how you're doing to the list but maybe consider removing the iteration as that's setting a limit on how many numbers you can store in the list..I maybe wrong as well but was thinking just doing: `prime_list = []
lcm_list = []` respectively you will still get all your factors in the list be 2,2 for 4,6...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of initializing the lists with a certain number of empty sublists, you can initialize them as empty lists, and append a new empty sublist for each iteration:

```
lcm_list = []
prime_list = []
for i in range(len(nums)):
    lcm_list.append([])
    prime_list.append([])
    for j in range(2, nums[i]):
        ...
```

Answer (score 2):

When you append you just have to have the values in square brackets to add a list into your list

```
a = []
b = [2,3]
c = [3]

#start with an empty array
print(a)
#[]

#add additional lists with whatever, this one has 2 values
a.append(b)
print(a)
#[[2, 3]]

#this just pushes the one
a.append(c)
print(a)
#[[2, 3], [3]]
```